# Setup Mongo DB with Sitecore 9.2

Tags: xdb, mongodb

I have installed Sitecore 9.2 XP0 Single Machine instance, using MS SQL Server for xDB. Now I have a requirement to replace MS SQL Server with Mongo DB for xDB. I have installed Mongo DB 4.0.5, as per the compatibility table. 
I need help on further steps on how to set this up. Do I need to manually create any DB instance inside Mongo DB, or are there any scripts for that?

Comment: Hi @sharad are you able to setup mongo db with 9.2? I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**MongoDB** is an open-source database management system (DBMS), usually called **NoSQL** database that uses a document-oriented database model which supports various forms of data. It means you don't need to create any table or database also you don't need to run/create any script for this.

All you need to do some configuration changes, because the default Sitecore is configure with MSSQL. You can find the configuration changes in `Installation Guide for the XP Scaled topology` file under the 9.2 download section- https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/92/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_92_Initial_Release.aspx

Basic steps are as follow -

NOTE: The follow are done in the xConnect site (`xconnect\App_Data\Config\Sitecore\Collection`) and the Indexing service (`xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\config\sitecore\Collection`)

1. Enable the `sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.MongoDb.xml.disabled` configuration file by
   removing .disabled extension.
2. Disable the `sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.Sql.xml` configuration file by adding the .disabled
3. Update the collection connection string to point to the MongoDB instance. It will look like this `<add name="collection" connectionString="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/usms_collection" />`
   You must also update the collection connection string in the indexer job that exists under the following roles:
   [image]
4. Rebuild the xDB search indexes in Solr. See the section Rebuild the Search Indexes in the link

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer.